# Is strace changing the behavior of a command?

Tags: linux, performance, strace

I am trying to debug a problem on a linux server.

When I run `sudo ls /` the command takes several seconds to run. non-sudo `ls /` runs as expected.

I suspect it has something to do with auditing going on via `auditd` but I'm not certain.

Anyway, I then tried to run the command with strace: `strace sudo ls /`, and the command runs just fine. In other words, it appears I'm in a heisenbug, where using strace to observe the behavior is in fact changing the behavior.

So while I am ultimately interested in figuring out why `sudo ls /` takes so long, right now I'm really curious to learn how to use `strace` to figure this out, and figure out if I'm using `strace` wrong and how to use it correctly.

Comment: Try narrowing it down by doing `sudo true`. Also, note that you need to avoid any caching by the authentication modules. What PAM modules are you using, if any?